# Junit test does not update or delete user on sql in Java Hibernate Dao

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, junit, dao

I have a DAO User with Hibernate framework. 
I am doing some Junit test about it. Testing create/update/delete on user, works for create but not for update and delete but my test passed. 
I need to verify what is wrong with my update, delete functions.

I tried to add a session.save() befose the update NOK
I tried to replace session.update() to session.saveOrUpdate() NOK
I tried to use the user parameter instead of create a new user NOK

Junit function update/delete only displaying update and delete

```
@Test
public void testCreateUpdateDeleteUser(){
    User userCRUD = new User("morganeflamant@gmail.com", "admin", new 
    Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    userCRUD = serviceFacade.getUserDao().findUserById(userCRUD.getId_user());
    Assert.assertNotNull(userCRUD);
    userCRUD.setId_user(userCRUD.getId_user());
    userCRUD.setEmail("testmorgane@gmail.com");
    userCRUD.setRole("member");
    userCRUD = serviceFacade.getUserDao().updateUser(userCRUD);
    Assert.assertNotNull(userCRUD);
    Assert.assertNotNull(userCRUD.getUpdateAt());

    userCRUD = serviceFacade.getUserDao().findUserById(userCRUD.getId_user());
    Assert.assertTrue(serviceFacade.getUserDao().deleteUser(userCRUD));
}
```

Userdao update and delete function:

```
@Override
public User updateUser(User user) {
        Session session = SingletonHibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User u = new User(user.getId_user(), user.getEmail(), user.getRole(), user.getCreateAt(), user.getUpdateAt());
        u.setId_user(user.getId_user());
        u.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        u.setRole(user.getRole());
        u.setCreateAt(user.getCreateAt());
        u.setUpdateAt(user.getUpdateAt());

        session.saveOrUpdate(u);
        session.close();

        return u;
    }

@Override
    public boolean deleteUser(User user) {
        Session session = SingletonHibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        User u = (User) session.get(User.class, user.getId_user());
        if(u != null){
            session.delete(u);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In my db I actually have :
60
morganeflamant@gmail.com
admin
2019-07-19 13:38:19
2019-07-19 13:38:19

but I am supposed to have this:
60
testmorgane@gmail.com
admin
2019-07-19 13:38:19
2019-07-19 13:38:19

for the update part and the delete part I am not supposed to have the user 60.

UPDATE:
adding this line :
`session.getTransaction().commit();`
after the session.save() and the changes are done.
Thank you for your comments !

Comment: i do see you are beginning the transaction but not committing it

Comment: Also depending on how JUnit is configured, you might never see any changes on the database (what you actually want to have it like)

Comment: Are you using an in memory DB for testing?

Comment: Oh thank, you were right I completly forgot to commit the transaction ! Now it works well. I am using a bdd mysql with mysql on WampServer. And the configuration for this is in hibernate.cfg.xml